# How to get Facebook profile using Facebook API with email id as parameter?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, eclipse-rcp

I am developing an RCP application that takes an email ID and displays the Facebook profile associated with it in a view using the instance of Browser class. Does Facebook API provide such an option for searching by email id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook's FQL User table only has uid, username, and Name (user's full name) as indexable columns.  Searching by an email address is not supported by Facebook's public API.

[FQL User Table Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user/)

Comment: Can you please upvote my question and enable me to post questions again? I am currently blocked due to some criteria of Stackoverflow.